# Unable to run application using google big query with OAuth on docker container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are facing an issue on our application which uses google big query with OAuth authentication. When we run the application on docker container during runtime we get an authentication URL on the docker console like below :

Please open the following address in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=330834658013-dg6niu0iihdcatin3c3mi6haqebrjinm.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:61984/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

If we open the URL outside the container in the browser. We do not get the response and application get failed.
We tried to run the application other than docker container, we found that It automatically redirect to the browser and successfully get the response after that an folder named as 'credentials' containing StoredCredentials file is created locally which get referred next time for authentication.

As described above, due to authentication is not done by URL on docker container. The credential folder is also not created. Could you explain the resolution on priority.

We tried to run the application other than docker, It is running successfully. As it automatically redirect the URL and completes the authentication. Same is expected on docker container as well.

Comment: What does the Error say? We can't open the link, because it's blocked by your company...

Comment: @AndyNope Nothing is blocked in company. We are able to run the application other than docker. Can you read the description.

Comment: No I mean the link from gooleAPI

Comment: Looks like an issue in the "redirect_url" sending you back in a place that does not exist when the app runs in docker, while it is there otherwise